# Putting hex (or binary) data into Java strings

Tags: java

In C there is an escape sequence that lets you embed a hex (or binary) value into a string? Something like this.

```
String str = "12345" + "\x0B" + "Some additional text";
```

Is there a similar function in Java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. A `String` in Java is *just* a sequence of UTF-16 code units (which *usually* means "a sequence of characters", but characters outside the [Basic Multilingual Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) require two UTF-16 code units). If you need binary data in there as well, you shouldn't use a string.

Now you can include the Unicode character U+000B (line tabulation) in the string, using `\u000b` - but you need to make sure that's actually what you want to do.

If you're *actually* trying to mix text data and binary data, I'd encourage you not to do that - it's *very* easy to lose data or convert it badly. If you provide your actual requirements, we may be able to help you come up with a much better solution.

Comment: Hi Jon: I'll accept that your not supposed to embed Binary into a Java String, and know well what problems it can cause from 30 years++ of embedded systems programing but in this case it would have been a convenient solution. I'll just rewrite the code to treat the file as a binary file with embedded ASCII characters - Joe

Comment: @JoeCullity Sorry, but saying you have "30 years++ of [experience]" sounds quite childish given the fact that you're asking a basic question and you don't seem to have understood the basic answer of "just use `\u000b`". The number of years you've been doing something doesn't make you smarter it seems :)

Answer (score 4):

In Java you can use [`Integer.toString(int i, int radix)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString%28int,%20int%29).

For hexadecimal, this is

```
String str = "12345" + Integer.toString(0x0B, 16) + "Some additional text";
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java, `Strings` are Unicode text. They cannot embed arbitrary binary data. If you want, you can embed the Unicode U+000B LINE TABULATION character though:

```
String str = "12345\u000BSome additional text";
```

Answer (score 0):

As already stated, Java Strings are Unicode, therefore 2 bytes, and is represented internally as a [`char[]`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray--).

@Jon Skeet is right [saying](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17515530/1098603) *"If you need binary data in there as well, you shouldn't use a string"* (but then Jon Skeet is *always* right ;)): you should use a `byte[]`.

However, if you *really* need to use a String to store binary data (because it sometimes is out of your hands), a [`Charset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) will encode your String into a [`byte[]`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes-java.nio.charset.Charset-). And it turns out the [ISO-8859-1 charset](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html#ISO_8859_1) will map a `char` to a single `byte`:

```
String str = "aéç";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16)));
```

gives:

```
[97, -23, -25]
[97, -61, -87, -61, -89]
[-2, -1, 0, 97, 0, -23, 0, -25]
```

So you coud hack your way through it using the [`String(byte[], Charset)` constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-byte:A-java.nio.charset.Charset-) to store binary data:

```
String str = "12345_Some additional text"; // '_' for the replacement character
byte[] hack = str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
hack[5] = 0x0B; // Change it here
str = new String(hack, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1); // Put it back
```